# Is there a way to decode and encode this str_rot13(gzdeflate(gzcompress()))

Tags: php, security, encoding, reverse-engineering

I just started my Cyber Security and i have been doing some research for few days online about reverse engineering, so i came across an encoded php code which i was able to decode, but the problem i am having is encoding this code back to original encoded string.

This is the nested code below:

```
str_rot13(gzinflate(gzuncompress(gzinflate(gzuncompress(gzinflate(gzuncompress(gzinflate(gzuncompress(base64_decode(strrev($code)))))))))))
```

and this is how i have tried to encode it to original encoded string but it's not working, does anyone know how this can be done. I have been on this for some days.

```
str_rot13(gzdeflate(gzcompress(gzdeflate(gzcompress(gzdeflate(gzcompress(gzdeflate(gzcompress(base64_encode(strrev()))))))))));
```

Comment: If you rot13 last on decode, you must do it first on encode

Comment: All your decoding operations need to be in reverse order of the encodings.

Comment: Thanks so much, it works fine in t he reverse order, dou the newly generated encoded string is not the same as the original string; but it works fine.